# Twig is not calling getter method of object property

Tags: symfony, twig

```
I have this class,


class SecurityStat
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $number_of_holders;

    /**
    * Set number_of_holders
    *
    * @param integer $numberOfHolders
    * @return SecurityStat
    */
    public function setNumberOfHolders($numberOfHolders)
    {
      $this->number_of_holders = $numberOfHolders;

      return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get number_of_holders
    *
    * @return integer 
    */
    public function getNumberOfHolders()
    {
      return $this->number_of_holders;
    }

}


Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SecurityStat:
  type: entity
  table: security_stats
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    number_of_holders:
      type: integer
      length: 15
      nullable: true
```

In twig template file,

**{{ stat.number_of_holders }}**

As per this documentation,

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables

It should call stat.getNumberOfHolders() getter but I am getting error

Twig_Error_Runtime: Method "number_of_holders" for object "Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SecurityStat" does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its pretty much what the error message says, your property is accessible via your getter `getNumberOfHolders` so the property access path should be `{{ stat.numberOfHolders }}`

The call you make in twig must match the actual method name in your class, there is no *magic* way for twig to know that your private property `number_of_holders` is accessible via your method `getNumberOfHolders`.

Comment: Hell yes there is a "magic way", it is called an inflector, which Doctrine use for exemple. Actually I belive it is a shame that twig doesn't use that.

Comment: I understand your argument but disagree in this particular case - the property has been defined as private, exposing its value trough its getter via inflection but still keeping its "original" name would be confussing and obfuscate the real problem here, which is an inconsistent naming strategy

Comment: I don't see how it is inconsistent. The propert is private, to not allow direct access and/or heritance access. The user tries to use the property in a twig, so I don't why it should try to use the property getter, which name is standard : get + camlized name. Is your point "if inflector is used, then you cannot distinct a direct access to a public property and its getter" ? If so, yes I agree, but direct access to a propert is a bad practice so ... :/ makes me think

Comment: In my opinion the naming strategy for properties and methods should be identical, so having a method that uses `lowerCamelCase` while using `underscore_naming`is *inconsistent* and should not be 'encouraged' like it would have been in this scensrio.
However this is only _my_ opinion which i gave to provide context for my awnser above.

Comment: Additionaly an `inflector` would expose the get method, not the property itself, which i was referring to in my awnser.